# macos rename folder - "OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1" - how fix it?

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, file

I have flutter app for macos. This is a service appl for working with files and folders. in the process of work, I need to rename several folders:

- there is a "main folder" - located in Documents/parent folder/
- is a "subfolder" - located in Documents/parent folder/main folder/

I successfully rename "subfolder" but when i rename "parent folder" i get error:

```
 OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1
```

I gave my app "Full disk access" but it didn't help

"main folder" will contain xCode project, when I try to rename "main folder" xCode and Finder is closed.

any advice - I will be grateful

Comment: Run `ls -l ~/Documents` and check permissions and ownership of `main folder`

Comment: I checked it
"main folder" - drwxr-xr-x@
"subfolder" -    drwxr-xr-x